# Using PLC with Modbus/TCP to read external Schneider PM5320 register

Tags: plc, modbus-tcp

I am very new to the world of automation and PLC. I am using a Schneider PM5320 to read some voltage and current values. I then want to take these values and send them to my Unitronics (USC-B10-R38) PLC. I am using Modbus/TCP communication protocol. I have set up the Modbus slave in Unilogics (Unistream) and I was able to read some registers, but the relevant register I wanted (L-N average Voltage) shows 0.

I used a generic Modbus tester to see if I could see these values. [image]

As shown above, the voltage value are stored in two registers namely 3036 and 3037. These values in the registers were correct and corresponded with the value shown on the meter.

For reference, I used Registers 1 to 3 to check if the PLC is actually "seeing" the registers and the values. As shown beloe here is the values as seen by die modbus tester:[image]

And here is the register values as shown through Unilogics, Keep in mind there is a offset of one:[image]

As seen above, the PLC is correctly seeing Registers 1 to 3 but is failing to correctly retrieve registers 3036 to 3038.

Why is this happening?

Comment: In your second image, you've cut off the definitions of `TestRegister_3036`, `TestRegister_3037` and `TestRegister_3038`.  Can you update the image to show these

Comment: Extrapolating from your Test Register naming, you may have applied the offset by 1 in the wrong direction.  MB Register 403035 should be `TestRegister_3034` (just as MD 400001 is  `TestRegister_0`)

Comment: Thank you Chris. I have gad success in reading the registers now. But one strange thing is that I had to add the registers up to 3038 in order to display the value on the plc. Would you maybe know why this is?

Comment: Sorry Corne, I'm not familiar with the specific instruments you're using